# Let $G$ be solvable. Let $g\in G$. What can we say about $g=[g^{x_1}, g^{y_1}]\dots [g^{x_n}, g^{y_n}]$ with $x_i,y_i\in G,i=1,...,n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

We have $G$ a solvable group. Let g be an element of G. What can we say about

$$g = [g^{x_{1}}, g^{y_{1}}]\cdot\cdot\cdot[g^{x_{n}}, g^{y_{n}}]$$

with $x_{i}, y_{i} \in G, i = 1,..., n$?

Comment: By $g^{x_i}$ do you mean a power of $g$? If so, this equation is false unless $g = e$ -- this is just because powers of $g$ always commute.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Considering $x_i \in G$, I suspect that this is notation for "the conjugate of $g$ by $x_i$".

Comment: @DuncanRamage Thank you, that was silly of me! I should have read the question carefully.

Comment: By the way, in this forum,  you are expected to offer your own thoughts on the question when asking for help. You are getting downvotes and votes to close because you failed to do this.

Answer (score 3):

If $G$ is finite, then by an absurd-sounding result of John Wilson, $n\leq 55$. This appears in J. London Math. Soc., entitled *Finite Axiomatization of Finite Soluble Groups*. The theorem is as follows:

A finite group $G$ is soluble if and only if no non-trivial element $g$ can be expressed as a product of 56 commutators of conjugates of $g$.

It is likely that the number 56 can be reduced.

Comment: I call this 'absurd-sounding' because when I was a Ph.D. student and John told me he had proved this, I didn't believe him. While some people think the best theorems are those people respond "Wow, X proved that?" to, I personally think the best theorems are those to which you respond "What? No, you must have got the statement wrong. There's no way that's true."

Comment: Well I challenge you to come up with any such expression in a soluble group! (I suspect that it is the "if" past of Wilson's theorem that is tricky to prove.)